# Laravel 5 - Using Package inside helpers.php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this `ColorThief\ColorThief` package that works well inside a controller.

However, I want to create a function `getImageColor($imgName)` in `helper.php` to consume `ColorThief\ColorThief` so I can use `getImageColor($imgName)` directly from views.

How can I access `ColorThief\ColorThief` from inside `helper.php`.

---

```
use ColorThief\ColorThief;

function getImageColor($img='') {
    if(!empty($img)) {
        $upload_path = public_path() . '/uploads/'.$img;
        if(file_exists($upload_path)) {
            return ColorThief::getColor($upload_path);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I call `getImageColor('image.jpg')`, I get the following error:

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/userxyz/public_html/dev/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

**Please note that when `ColorThief::getColor($upload_path);` is used inside a controller, it works perfectly**.

Comment: a little confused on what you actually want because if you want a function to have a class object in it then you will instantiate it inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `helper.php` you can use it like this:

```
use ColorThief\ColorThief;

function getImageColor($sourceImage)
{
    return ColorThief::getColor($sourceImage);
}
```

> The $sourceImage variable must contain either the absolute path of the
>   image on the server, a URL to the image, a GD resource containing the
>   image, an Imagick image instance, a Gmagick image instance, or an
>   image in binary string format. [Package Github Repository](https://github.com/ksubileau/color-thief-php).

### Update:

> This function returns an array of three integer values, corresponding
>   to the RGB values (Red, Green & Blue) of the dominant color. Example:
>   `array(r: num, g: num, b: num)`

Further to convert the `RGB` to `HEX` you may use the following function:

```
function rgb2hex($rgb)
{
    $hex .= str_pad(dechex($rgb[0]), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $hex .= str_pad(dechex($rgb[1]), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $hex .= str_pad(dechex($rgb[2]), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return "#".$hex;
}
```

For example:

```
$color = rgb2hex(getImageColor($sourceImage)); // #ffffff for white
```

Comment: It's happening in your `welcome.blade.php` blade template and this is happening because you are probably trying to echo something using `{{ $someThing }}` where `$something` is n array. The function is alright and error is in your view. Notice the return value of the function call, which is an array like `returns array(r: num, g: num, b: num)`, so if you try to echo the return value then it'll not work. Check the documentation (Github) to learn more about  this.